# How would I testfor players scoreboard amount in a specific location?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have been trying to find a way to testfor a player with a score of 1 in a z.y.z.r location. what I've tried was
`/testfor @p[X,Y,Z,R,score_Var_min=1,score_Var=1]` but it doesn't seem to want to work.

Comment: I found it never mind.

Comment: If you found it, maybe post an answer about it? ;)

Comment: This question is not unclear, it asks how to `/testfor` a player with a score of 1, who is at specific coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation of the question isn't clear enough.
(What do you mean by 'Z'.Y.Z.'R'?)
You may try to use this parameter:

```
/testfor @p[x=var,y=var,z=var,score_var_min=var,score_var=var]
```

With the word `var` replaced.

**EDIT:**
Just noticed the mistake, You cannot assign score_var_min and score_var on a one command.
The command you should use is :

```
/testfor @p[x=var,y=var,z=var,score_var=var]
```

or :

```
/testfor @p[x=var,y=var,z=var,score_var_min=var]
```